# AttributeError: module 'slack' has no attribute 'RTMClient'

Tags: python, pycharm, slack

I getting below error on running my python file slack_rtmClient.py in Pycharm

```
   C:\Users\A6002043\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe C:/Users/A6002043/IdeaProjects/iptautobot/slack_rtmClientnew.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
C:\Users\A6002043\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\slack\__init__.py
  File "C:/Users/A6002043/IdeaProjects/iptautobot/slack_rtmClientnew.py", line 10, in <module>
    @slack.RTMClient.run_on(event='message')
AttributeError: module 'slack' has no attribute 'RTMClient'
```

Sample code in slack_rtmClient.py file

```
import os
import re
from builtins import len, Exception
import slack
import logging
from subprocess import check_output
import datetime
print(slack.__file__)


@slack.RTMClient.run_on(event='message')
def say_hello(**payload):
    try:
```

Comment: How did you install the slack module?  Do you have a local file named `slack.py`?

Comment: How did you originally install the slack module?  Did you use `pip`, or something else?

Comment: @JohnGordon  I didn't do anything separately other than installing Pycharm and running this file in pycharm

Comment: The slack module isn't built in to python, so you would have had to install it somehow.  I wonder if you have a local file named `slack.py` which is being imported instead of the "real" module (which isn't installed at all).  Try adding this code after the imports: `print(slack.__file__)` and show us the output.

Comment: I have added print statement as you mentioned but i see the same output.

Comment: What is the output of the `print()`?  That should show up before the error.

Comment: my bad sorry , yes i see it here is the output     C:\Users\A6002043\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\slack\__init__.py

Comment: Hmm, looking at the slack documentation, it appears that `RTMClient` is an optional sub-module within slack, that you have to install separately.

Comment: No, the RTMClient not an optional sub-module. Looks to me like you have accidentally installed the old v1 version of the slackclient? To get the correct version try this: `pip3 install slackclient --upgrade`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

**1.** Open **PyCharm**.

**2.** go to `File -> settings -> Project:test(test means your project name) -> select project interpretor -> click add button`

[image]

**3.** after click add button search `slack-rtm-bot` then **install** it.

finally run the program.

- Remember `slack-rtm-bot` installed only this project. if you have started another project based on `RTMClient` you have to install that interpreter again.